# Perl - locate the latest subdirectory on a network path and copy the entire contents

Tags: perl

I want to locate the latest subdirectory on a network path and copy the entire contents of the latest subdirectory into another folder in the network path

We have lot of subfolders under the folder `\\10.184.132.202\projectdump` I need to sort the sub folders to get into latest folder and copy the entire contents into another folder on `\\10.184.132.203\baseline`

I am using the below mentioned script i am able to list the latest modified folder under the directory but I am unaware of copying the contents.

```
use File::stat;
use File::Copy qw(copy);
$dirname = '\\\\10.184.132.202\\projectdump\\Testing\\';
$destination = '\\\\10.184.132.203\\baseline\\Testing\\';
$timediff=0;
opendir DIR, "$dirname";
while (defined ($sub_dir = readdir(DIR)))
{
    if($sub_dir ne "." && $sub_dir ne "..")
    {
        $diff = time()-stat("$dirname/$sub_dir")->mtime;
        if($timediff == 0)
        {
            $timediff=$diff;
            $newest=$sub_dir;
        }
        if($diff<$timediff)
        {
            $timediff=$diff;
            $newest=$sub_dir;
        }
    }
}
print $newest,"\n";

open my $in, '<', $newest or die $!;
while (<$in>) {
    copy *, $destination; --------> Here i want to copy the entire contents of the $newest to $destination.
}
```

Comment: Use the File::Copy module.  Also, you are checking the return code of `open`, but not `opendir`.  That can fail, too.  Also, there's no need to put `$dirname` in quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Use [File::Copy::Recursive](http://search.cpan.org/~dmuey/File-Copy-Recursive-0.38/Recursive.pm). This is an optional module, but allows you to copy entire directory trees. Unfortunately, `File::Copy::Recursive` is not a standard Perl module, but you can install it via the `cpan` command.

If installing modules is a problem (sometimes it is), you can use the [File::Find](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html) to go through the directory tree and copy files one at a time.

By the way, you can use forward slashes in Perl for Windows file names, so you don't have to double up on backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't call a simple shell cmd to find the latest dir?
I think, this will be much simpler in shell...

```
my $newestdir=`ls -1rt $dirname|tail -n 1`;
```

in shell:

```
LATESTDIR=`ls -1rt $dirname|tail -n 1`
cp -r ${LATESTDIR}/* $destination/
```

Ups, I just realized that you might using Windows...

Get all dirs and their times into a hash then sort that hash reverse order to find the newest one

```
my ($newest) = sort {$hash{$b} cmp $hash{$a} keys %hash;
```

then

```
opendir NDIR, "$newest";
while ($dir=<NDIR>) {
next if $dir eq '.' or $dir eq '..';
copy $dir, $destination;
}
```

Comment: After sorting i am still unable to copy the files.